# Extract sub-matrix using logical indexing in Stata?

Tags: stata

Naive Stata user like me who only intends to do some basic estimation job are often quite unfamiliar with Stata's matrix feature, and Mata syntax. However, in some cases, the technique is needed. For example, recently I want to use the “High-dimensional Lasso IV” approach imposed by [Belloni et al.(2014)](http://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/jep.28.2.29) ( the bottom paragraph of Page40), their method includes a “Preliminary Data Cleaning” :

(1). Create interaction term between every bivariate-variable pair, and high order terms for many variables.

(2) Calculate the correlation matrix and drop those variables with significant high correlation (keep only one variable in this case).

(3) Identify those variables of significant small standard errors and drop them.

Finally, keep the remaining variables and use them as instrumental variables.

The original code was is written in Matlab. Clearly, the first step is easy enough within Stata ( simplest method is also welcomed). But for the remaining two steps, they are essentially a task of logical indexing and some knowledge of matrix manipulation in Mata is required (My observations are over 800).

In my very limited understanding, the outline of code to deal with this problem should be like (only pseudo code, details and corrections needed )

```
    local varlist var_1 var_2 ······ var_n
    correlate `varlist'


   mata:
   // Import rreturn from --correlate--, need st_local()?
   corr = st_matrix("r(C")
   index= selectindex(corr:<=.99)
   corr[.,index]
   // Finally we want to tranfer the matrix back to stata memory
```

So what I want is how to adjust my code to achieve my goal, or there is more convenient way to finish the same work. Dive into Mata may the final solution but currently, I don't have so much time. Thank you for your help.

Aside, the Matlab code snippet is below

```
xxinv = inv(x'*x);
My = full(y - x*xxinv*(x'*y)); %#ok<*MINV>
Md = full(d - x*xxinv*(x'*d));
Mz = full(z - x*xxinv*(x'*z));

I = find(std(Mz) > 1e-6);
Mz = Mz(:,I);  % Identify those instruments of large enough sd. and keep them (P40)
IND_dem = IND_dem(I);
namez = namez(I);

[I,J] = find(abs(tril(corr(Mz)-eye(size(Mz,2)))) > .99); % Identify those instruments of high bivariate correlated and drop them (P40)
drop = unique(I);
Mz(:,drop) = [];
IND_dem(drop) = [];
namez(drop) = [];

n = size(Mz,1);
p = size(Mz,2);
kx = size(x,2);
```

Comment: https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1410310-new-stata-command-for-lasso-ridge-regression-and-elastic-net-regression seems pertinent. Wanting a translation of a sizeable code chunk may be optimistic here, but who knows.

Comment: Fragmentary references like Belloni et al. 2014 put the onus on readers to search and perhaps guess what you mean. Better to give complete references and/or a durable link, as you know them. Just consider roles reversed, e.g. I mention Miles et al. 2013.

Comment: Thanks, Nick, article link has been added

Comment: My problem relates more to the data pre-cleaning process, which itself a matter of submatrix extraction using logical indexing, than to the actual lasso estimation implementation. So would you mind take a look?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know MATLAB at all well enough to make the question straightforward. I've used it about twice and remember nothing much.

Comment: The MATLAB code has a number of variables that are not defined. Please post a working example if you want that translated. Also, I think you are looking for `corr = st_matrix("r(C)")` to get the correlation matrix and `index = selectindex(corr :<= 99)` for the elements. After that you can do `corr[, index]`.

Comment: Subsequently cross-posted to Statalist's Mata Forum at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/mata/1410958-variable-list-extraction-using-logical-indexing-in-mata

Comment: @Mauricio Sorry for the inconvenience I brought. The original code is too long to parse completely without inflence the readability. I was supposed to upload it to dropbox however I'm from China and open the dropbox website is difficult. Anyway,you can find the code from http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/christian.hansen/research/ under title "Code for Lasso" and .m file CSHomePriceMakeStataData is what you need.

Comment: @Mauricio . Following your suggestion, I edit my code snippet in the question description. However, I still confused how to feed the calculated submatrix `corr` back to stata? Using `st_view`? I'm quite ignorant of mata interface.

Comment: Redirect to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327098/data-transfer-between-mata-and-stata

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct response to your question on Stata/Mata programming, but I thought I mention that the Lasso-based estimation methods proposed by Belloni, Chernozhukov, Hansen et al are available in the Stata package [pdslasso](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s458459.html). From the abstract:

> pdslasso and ivlasso are routines for estimating structural parameters
>   in linear models with many controls and/or instruments. The routines
>   use methods for estimating sparse high-dimensional models,
>   specifically the lasso (Least Absolute Shrinkage and Selection
>   Operator, Tibshirani 1996) and the square-root-lasso (Belloni et al.
>   2011, 2014). These estimators are used to select controls (pdslasso)
>   and/or instruments (ivlasso) from a large set of variables (possibly
>   numbering more than the number of observations), in a setting where
>   the researcher is interested in estimating the causal impact of one or
>   more (possibly endogenous) causal variables of interest. Two
>   approaches are implemented in pdslasso and ivlasso: (1) The
>   "post-double-selection" (PDS) methodology of Belloni et al. (2012,
>   2013, 2014, 2015, 2016). (2) The "post-regularization" (CHS)
>   methodology of Chernozhukov, Hansen and Spindler (2015). For
>   instrumental variable estimation, ivlasso implements
>   weak-identification-robust hypothesis tests and confidence sets using
>   the Chernozhukov et al. (2013) sup-score test. The implemention of
>   these methods in pdslasso and ivlasso require the Stata program rlasso
>   (available in the separate Stata module lassopack), which provides
>   lasso and square root-lasso estimation with data-driven penalization.

You will also need to install the package [lassopack](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s458458.html), which pdslasso relies on. To install pdslasso/lassopack, type

```
ssc install lassopack 
ssc install pdslasso
```